# Generating checkbox for if string in model is null inside List<model> inside viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel that includes an icollection of models from the db with a string attribute. I am trying to index those models from the viewmodel in a table but instead of writing the string out, I want to generate a checkbox using razor for whether the string is null or not. Is there a simple way to do this that I am not seeing? I keep getting null reference errors or nothing at all.

here is my viewmodel:

```
public class CourseViewModel
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Course Name")]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<NewPage> CoursePages { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CoursePages)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PageNumber)
    </td>
    @*<td>
        @if (item.DrillInstructions == null)
        {
            Html.CheckBox("Instructions", false);
        }
        @if (item.DrillInstructions != null)
        {
            Html.CheckBox("Instructions", true);
        }
    </td>*@
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DrillInstructions)
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for display, you could use a glyphicon or [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/). Something like

```
<td>
    <i class='fa @(item.DrillInstructions == null ? "fa-square" : "fa-checksquare")'></i>
</td>
```

Use fa fa-2x for a bigger checkbox.